# Java String.split error

Tags: java, string, split

My method successfully takes a binary expression tree and turns it into prefix, postfix, and infix notation. However, due to the accuracy of the final string, it must be exactly equal.

So before I return my output, I will run a method to quickly edit that output to remove any flaws.

> (* (+ 8 4) (- 7 (/ 6 3))) ===> (*(+ 8 4)(- 7(/ 6 3)))
>
> ((8 4 +) (7 (6 3 /) -) *)  =====>    ((8 4 +)(7 (6 3 /)-)*)

What needs to be changed, are the spacing inbetween parens. My goal was to find all cases of a string, remove them, and reinput in the string without spaces.

> **underlines are extra spaces**
> (**(+ 8 4)*(- 7_(/ 6 3)))

My code was supposted to be `String.split(") (");` but error signs... `unmatched closing ')')(???`

```
public String antibullshiter(String out) {
    out = out.replaceFirst(") (", "X"); //edited
    String[] parts = out.split("X");
    String part1 = parts[0];
    String part2 = parts[1];
    part1 = part1 + ")";
    part2 = part2 + "(";
    out = part1 + part2;
return out;}
```

How do I harness the power of String.split()?

**edit: thanks guys, but I realized I just had to deal with the primary method in itself**

Comment: You need to understand [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/), as `split()` does no use plain strings to split on

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the other answers / comments, `String.split` takes a pattern string (regular expression), and that's why you're getting the unmatched parenthesis error. You can use the [`Pattern.quote`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) method to get the pattern string that would match your string literal:

```
yourString.split(java.util.regex.Pattern.quote(") ("));
```

Answer (score 0):

As, `String` is immutable. To got the changes of `replaceFirst` method, you  need to re-assign with `out`. Also you need to skip the Meta Character.

```
  out=out.replaceFirst("\\)\\s*\\(", "X");
```

Comment: I have done what you have asked. out = out.replaceFirst(") (", "X");   but nothing has changed with the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Use `s.replaceAll("(?<=\\))\\s(?=\\()","")` to remove the spaces

the error is because the string is a regex string, and parenteses must be escaped with double backslash (`"\\("`) otherwise they have special meaning.

Edit: use `s.replaceAll("(?<=\\))\\s+(?=\\()","")` for multiple spaces

Comment: This regex will not remove multiple (consecutive) spaces

Comment: @cosjav I assumed that the OP's code would have each node put one space in between its sub-nodes. Though your point is taken

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regular expression to remove spaces surrounding parenthesis:

`out=out.replaceAll("\\s*([()])\\s*", "$1");`

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It replaces the string.

```
out.replaceFirst("\\) \\(", "X");
```